# Net Core 3.0 and Serilog producing output like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core, serilog

I have a simple web app using .Net Core 3.0.

In my host builder I do this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console());
```

I then try to implement it in another project (simple dll using netcoreapp3.0) being referenced by the web app project:

```
using using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
...
private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger){
  _logger = logger;
  ...
  Log.Logger.Information("this is a test {test}", command.GetType().Name);

  _logger.LogInformation("Command received: {CommandType}", command.GetType().Name);
}
...
```

The static logger works fine but the _logger's output is as if I use the default logging. But as far as I understand from reading [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore), the host builder now has the ILoggerFactory replaced and should output Serilog styled output.

[image: These are my two outputs, first from the static and then from _logger]

How can I get the _logger output to be as neat as the Serilog one?

Comment: Very strange! Are you able to reproduce the issue in a toy project? (I.e. a _File > New Project_ EXE and accompanying class library?) If so, and you can post it as a repo or gist, I'll hit it with a debugger! :-)

Comment: Intresting. My toy project is working fine when I try to reproduce it. In the main project, this happens when the web app is getting a message from a message queue and fires up the listener hooked to the queue. I'll see if I can reconstruct that behaviour in my toy project.

Comment: Okay, a bit embarrassing but I finally solved it. I'll post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was experiencing was that whenever I caught a queue-event, the log used Microsoft.Extensions.Logging styled logging.

This seems to be because the event listener was somehow registered BEFORE the logging factory was replaced but executed AFTER, which led to the weird logging. My solution was doing this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console());
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```